# Tamanho dos index de um banco de dados mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query, índices

Como seria a estrutura de uma `query` para conseguir obter o tamanho total em `MB` de todos os `index` das tabelas de um determinado `banco de dados` em `mysql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja isso:

```
select database_name, table_name, index_name, stat_value*@@innodb_page_size
from mysql.innodb_index_stats where stat_name='size';
```

Esse também é interessante:

```
SELECT concat(table_schema,'.',table_name),
concat(round(table_rows/1000000,2),'M') rows,
concat(round(data_length/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') DATA,
concat(round(index_length/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') idx,
concat(round((data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') total_size,
round(index_length/data_length,2) idxfrac 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY data_length+index_length DESC LIMIT 20;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781873/how-to-figure-out-size-of-indexes-in-mysql

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda porém consegui fazer de outra forma